# TOAD have the option to create insert script to add new data?

Tags: oracle, toad

In postgresql I can select a table and generate an insert script:

> Right click on table > Scripts > INSERT Script

[image]

And get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO categories(
            category_id, name, created_time, description)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Can I do something similar on TOAD?

Until now only found export table but that create inserts for all the data there.

Comment: Does Toad let you drag a table name from the object browser into an editor window? Some tools work that way and will present you with generation options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Schema Browser, right-click table name and - in the menu that appears - select "Generate Statement". Pick the one you need (insert / select / merge / update).

Comment: Ok, thanks I stop looking after the `Create Script` option. Worth mention that command copy the statement to the clipboard so need paste to the editor.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, *where* would it be copied? If Editor is closed, there's nowhere to *paste* that code; right? So, clipboard seems to be appropriate.

Comment: Well editor was open. And in postgresql you get a new editor open with the statement. Also you dont get any indication the statement was copy to the clipboard so after a few attempt I thought wasnt working. Lucky I decide try paste. But isnt intuitive that is why I comment.

Comment: OK, no problem.